# Azure Data Factory: Sending An Email When Pipeline Failed

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using Web Activity on my Pipeline. The Activity was used for sending an email, if the previous activity is failed.

I want to use the dynamic content on its Body, but it keeps sending the string. The dynamic content is this: "@concat('testing_',formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(), -1), 'MMddyyyy'), '.csv')".

What is the workaround for this issue?

Please help, thanks!

Comment: can you show us some screenshoots?

Comment: Hi @Chataby Nabyl, welcome to stack overflow.  If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. If you have any other concerns, please feel free to let me know.  Reply us can help you get more helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the body expression, and it works well.

**Web active Body:**

[image]

Even if the active failed, but the body get the correct result "testing_12082020.csv"(today is 12092020):

[image]

If you want to send file to the endpoint, you should set the dataset operation. For example, create a dataset with parameter:
[image]

Pass the expression to the filename:
[image]

HTH.